# Spring Boot Soap WSDL doesnt contain anything wsdl:portType section

Tags: spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, jaxb2

I am new to SOAP webservices development using spring and I have referred the following website for my soap ws development.`https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-web-service-example`. I have setup the demo application i am able to generate the wsdl file. however when I used my project related XSD file it is generated wsdl file but it doesnt contain anything under `wsdl:portType` section.

I have used the following xsd file to generate wsdl based on `DefaultWsdl11Definition`.  my xsd file is here.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/"
       targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified">

                                            <xs:simpleType name="StatusCode">
                                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                                            <xs:enumeration value="OK"/>
                                                                            <xs:enumeration value="REQUEST_ERROR"/>
                                                                            <xs:enumeration value="APPLICATION_ERROR"/>
                                                            </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>

                                            <xs:complexType name="PatientStatus">
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                            <xs:element name="errorDescription" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                            <xs:element name="statusCode" type="tns:StatusCode"/>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>

                                            <xs:complexType name="parameters">
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="parameter">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                                            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>

                                            <xs:element name="createCaseForPatientRequestBody">
                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                                            <xs:element name="caseId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element name="caseXML" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="entityType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="entityInstance" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parameters" nillable="true" type="tns:parameters"/>
                                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element>

                                            <xs:element name="createCaseForPatientSResponseBody">
                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                                            <xs:element name="caseId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element name="screensURL" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                                                                                            <xs:element name="patientStatus" nillable="false" type="tns:PatientStatus"/>
                                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element>
                            </xs:schema>
```

Please correct me where I am doing wrong.I have been trying to figure out the issue. Please help. Thanks in advance .

End Point

```
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.com/";
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "createCaseForPatient")
@ResponsePayload
public createCaseForPatientResponse createCase(@RequestPayload createCaseForPatientRequest request) {
    createCaseForPatientResponse response = new createCaseForPatientResponse();
    response.setCaseId("ABC123");
    response.setScreensURL("www.patientinfo.org");
    response.setPatientStatus("ACTIVE")
    return response;
}
```

wsconfig.java

```
public class WSConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/soapws/*");
}
@Bean(name = "articles")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema articlesSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ArticlesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/soapws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.example.com/");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(articlesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
@Bean
public XsdSchema articlesSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/articles.xsd"));
}
}
```

Comment: You have to give more information about what you've done. Can you post your endpoint (class annotated with @Endpoint) definition.

Comment: and the update of your configuration (class WSConfig)

Comment: @AkliREGUIG - I have updated both endpoint and wsconfig file for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `DefaultWsdl11Definition` define the request type suffix as `Request` and the response type suffix as `Response`. 
This can be customised during the bean initialisation is needed.

update your xsd so the response and the request are named as follow :

```
...
    <xs:element name="createCaseForPatientRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="caseId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="caseXML" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="entityType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="entityInstance" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parameters" nillable="true" type="tns:parameters"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="createCaseForPatientResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="caseId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="screensURL" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="patientStatus" nillable="false" type="tns:PatientStatus"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
...
```

and your operation definition as follow :

```
//...
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "createCaseForPatientRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public CreateCaseForPatientResponse createCaseForPatient(@RequestPayload CreateCaseForPatientRequest request) {
        CreateCaseForPatientResponse response = new CreateCaseForPatientResponse();
        response.setCaseId("ABC123");
        response.setScreensURL("www.patientinfo.org");
        response.setPatientStatus(new PatientStatus());
        return response;
    }
//...
```